# GUI python file import

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I have to write a program by python language, that implement three different algorithms for convex hull computing with GUI to choose the files containing the data and to show summary results.

i'm using tkniter for the GUI,i have issues importing the data file from the pc and save the data in a list.
this is my code

```
def OpenFile ():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    lines = filename.readlines()
    filename.close()

root = Tk()
root.title('convex hull')
root.geometry('400x300')
label1 = ttk.Label(root,text="Enter points").place(x=20,y=3)
label2 = ttk.Label(root,text = "Choose One of the algorithm to sort the points").place(x=0,y=60)
btn1= ttk.Button(root,text="Browse", command = OpenFile)
btn1.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not ask a question, but there are at least three problems with the code.  1. The local variable `lines` disappears as soon as `OpenFile` returns.  Make lines a global variable and declare it as such.  2. `label1` and `label2` will both be `None` as that is the return value of `place`.  3. You use two geometry managers.  Pick one.  (I recommend `grid`, but went with `pack` here.)

```
def OpenFile ():
    global lines 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    lines = filename.readlines()
    filename.close()

root = Tk()
root.title('convex hull')
root.geometry('400x300')
label1 = ttk.Label(root,text="Enter points")
label1.pack()
label2 = ttk.Label(root,text = "Choose One of the algorithm to sort the points")
label2.pack()
btn1= ttk.Button(root,text="Browse", command = OpenFile)
btn1.pack()
```